# Qt Error: QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component, [...path]\main.qml: Network Error

Tags: qt, pyside, qml

Estoy intentando iniciarme en el desarrollo de Python/Qt con PySide. Es la primera vez que uso Qt y estoy teniendo algunas dificultades respecto a QML, no consigo hacer que funcione debidamente.

Veréis, cuando abro un nuevo proyecto en blanco (Python QT Quick application - empty), esto es lo primero que veo en pantalla al entrar en modo diseño de QML; una pequeña ventana que luce "glitchy" y suelta una alerta que comenta que el elemento "Ventana" ("Window") no se pudo crear.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Conseguí resolver este problema cambiando mi QML Emulation Layer de "use fallback QML emulation layer" a "Use QML emulation layer that is built with the selected Qt" desde Tools>Options>Qt Quick>Qt Quick Designer.

Esto arregla el problema de la vista de Diseño y me permite editar el QML debidamente. Sin embargo, cuando intento compilar y ejecutar la aplicación en blanco (sin escribir nada de código, out of the box) consigo este mensaje de error en el Application Output:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
c:%5c(my project path)%5Cmain.qml: Network error
```

Estoy casi totalmente seguro de que este problema se deberá a un error muy tonto por mi parte debido a mi inexperiencia, pero no consigo arreglarlo y necesito ayuda, así que vengo humildemente a consultaros a vosotros, los sabios! haha x')

Actualmente estoy ejecutando la última versión disponible de Qt6, con pyside6 y python 3.10.0 en Windows 10.

Ya he probado a reinstalar Qt (muchas veces), también he probado diferentes builds (Qt5.15/pyside2 y algunas otras). También he probado con diferentes presets de aplicaciones Qt que no requieren Python, pero siempre consigo el mismo error de QML.

Por favor, si alguien pudiera ayudar estaría muy agradecido, llevo muchas horas estudiando este problema y no consigo dar con el arreglo, me estoy volviendo loco! haha.

Gracias por adelantado!

Edit: perdonad amigos, publiqué el tema en inglés en el foro español por error! Perdí un poco la práctica de español, pero intenté traducirlo al idioma lo mejor que pude.

Saludos y disculpas! :')

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta fue respondida en el foro inglés. Resulta que, aparentemente, el código de "main.py" auto-generado por Qt no es el más apropiado y genera problemas.

Para mi, la solución fue crear un QUrl para el método load() en "main.py":

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```